# Is there a glossaries package equivalent that doesn't require the preamble?

Tags: glossaries

I'm writing a technical book, which will be printed (no PDF). I'm in the need of a separate glossary chapter, and took a look at the `glossaries` package. The output from `\printglossaries` does match what I want visually, but the package seems to require you to define the glossary entries in the preamble, and this is something I do not want. I want to keep my preamble clean, short, and to the point, without bloating it with loads of glossary entries.

All my chapters are separate files, which I include using `\include{chapterXXX}` in the preamble. This is what I want to do with the glossaries as well: `\include{glossary}`, and in `glossary.tex` I want all the glossary entries. I have no interest in referencing them with hyperref, or similiar.

Question: Is it possible to use the glossaries using the above scenario? That is, *without* polluting preamble with entries.

Comment: Why not a separate file for the glossary entries, which you can `\input` in your preamble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Bernard, one can add the glossaries in a seperate file and include them via `\input`, either by using the relative or absolute path to the file.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt,openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%...
%relative path from within the workspace folder
%\input{<path/to/file.tex>}
\input{mysubfolder\myglossaries.tex}

%absolute path either within or outside the workspace folder
%\input{"C:\<path/to/file.tex>"}
%assuming Windows as the OS
\input{"C:\Documents\MyProject\MySubFolder\myglossaries.tex"}

\begin{document}
...
\printglossaries
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: That seems to work, but what does not seem to work is the `xindy` program (which is required for Latin-1, where `makeindex` is at a loss), but there is no Debian package for xindy anywhere. I tried to compile the sourcecode (latest release from 2008!), but that was a dead end.

So, me and the glossaries package are really no friends, it seems.

Comment: I will accept your answer, but I will search for another solution, because this tex package causes nothing but frustration for me. It does not work(tm).